# Jump to page location on base page using JavaScript in ApEx

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

I need to be able to jump to a location in a base page.

The base page contains a

```
<a id='jump_here'></a>
```

tag used to define the target location. Then, o the child page, the code below:

```
htp.p('<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">');
htp.p('// <!--');
htp.p('window.location = "f?p=&APP_ID.' || chr(58) || '401' || chr(58) || '&SESSION.' || chr(58) || chr(58) || '&DEBUG.' || chr(58) || chr(58) || 'P401_ID";' );
htp.p('window.location.hash = "jump_here";');
htp.p('// -->');
htp.p('</script>');
```

The problem is this doesn't work. Could someone please let me know what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Does the page open? Is the hash shown in the URL? Does manually putting the hash on the end of the URL work as expected?

Comment: "it doesn't work" means the base page opens, it just doesn't move to the specified location. It stays at the top.

Comment: So if you add the hash manually (to end of url and press enter), does it navigate down the page?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood where you are using that js code, but I believe you are trying to use anchor points and if that is the case you can append it to the end of your link url adding `#jump_here` to the end of your url:

```
f?p=APP_ID:PAGE_ID:SESSION:REQUEST:DEBUG:CLEAR_CACHE:ITEM_NAMES:ITEM_VALUE#ANCHOR_ID
```

Looking at your sample code I think you are missing the Item value parameter in your url. And you could probably use APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL instead, read more in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_util.htm#AEAPI160).

Comment: Same result as the initial code - the window opens, but it doesn't jump to the required location.

Comment: Can you show some screen shots or explain better where you are putting the `<a id='jump_here'></a>` code?